# Logging data to the console based on selections

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data like so:

```
var data = [
    ["Acid", 0.741593940836, 0.45657115],
    ["Cannabis", 0.94183423, 0.31475],
    ["LSD", 0.1367547, 0.936115]
];
```

Which plots points to a scatterplot.

I also have other arrays of data that look like this - the arrays are declared with the same names of each sub array in `data`. These arrays are then stored in an array:

```
var Acid = ["leak","advice", "draft","addition","genuine","object","advance","freshman","sour","say","page","old","loot","white","soul","wriggle","agony","sensitivity","laundry","format"];

var collection = [Acid, Cannabis, LSD];
```

I'm trying to create some code returns one (two or all) of the arrays (`Acid`, `Cannabis`, `LSD`) based on a selection of the points in the scatterplot. The code I have so far is as below - it should be noted that the selecting points is done via `Lasso`, I've included that code also.

```
var lasso_end = function() {

    lasso.items()
        .classed("not_possible",false)
        .classed("possible",false);

    var selected = lasso.selectedItems()
        .classed("selected", true)
        .attr("r", 13);

    var selectedPoints = [];

    selected.data().forEach((arr) => {
        arr.forEach((d) => {
            selectedPoints.push(d);
        });
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < selectedPoints.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < collection.length; j++) {
            if(selectedPoints[0] == collection[j]) {
                console.log(collection[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Just to reiterate, I'm trying log data from Arrays `Acid`, `Cannabis`, and `LSD` to the console, **if points in the array `data` is selected**

In response to one of the comments, I've put a `console.log()` after `selectedPoints` and this is the output and format:

[image]

Comment: what format is selectedPoints in?

Comment: @Roope I've included a screenshot of the output after logging `selectedPoints`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if I understand correctly, after doing

```
selected.data().forEach((arr) => {
    arr.forEach((d) => {
        selectedPoints.push(d);
    });
});
```

your selectedPoints array logs out as

```
"Acid",
0.123123,
0.123131,
"Cannabis"
0.232222,
0.221121... etc.
```

and then you want to console.log the arrays whose names are in the above output, here the arrays `Acid` and `Cannabis`.

The issue is that you create the array `collection` with named variables holding the word arrays: the names of the variables that held the arrays don't transfer, you can't do

```
var foo = 2
var array = [foo]
```

and the try to access the value with `array[foo]`, that's not how JS arrays work. They only have numerical indices.

You should use an object:

```
var collection = {
    Acid: ["leak","advice", "draft","addition","genuine","object","advance","freshman","sour","say","page","old","loot","white","soul","wriggle","agony","sensitivity","laundry","format"]
}
```

and then extraxt the names from `selectedPoints`

```
var pointNames = selectedPoints.filter(x => typeof x === "string")
```

and the loop through the pointNames array, logging out the corresponding *property* on the object `collection` if it exists. Here's a simplified snippet:

```js
var data = [
    ["Acid", 0.741593940836, 0.45657115],
    ["Cannabis", 0.94183423, 0.31475],
    ["LSD", 0.1367547, 0.936115]
];

var selectedPoints = ['Acid', 0.741593940836, 0.45657115];

var collection = {
  Acid: ["leak","advice", "draft","addition","genuine","object","advance","freshman","sour","say","page","old","loot","white","soul","wriggle","agony","sensitivity","laundry","format"]
}

var pointNames = selectedPoints.filter(x => typeof x === "string")

 pointNames.forEach(point => {
   if(collection[point]) {
    console.log(collection[point])
   }
 })
```